# Wed Scraping with BeautifulSoup not returning values

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm very new to scraping & been trying to do a project & have been following the instruction & managed to pass the error 403 by using User-Agent etc. which eventually gave me code 200 but the code from the start is not returning a value for the productlist & I cant figure out why, as I cant see any error in the code, any help would be much appreciated

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.controlleremea.co.uk/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://google.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Alan': 'subtomeplease'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.controlleremea.co.uk/listings/search?Category=3&page=1', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'list-listing-wrapper')

print(len(productlist))
```

Comment: Uhm, and what's your question?

Comment: The question is why the line below not returning any values when I can’t see anything wrong with it

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'list-listing-wrapper')
print(productlist)
Or
print(len(productlist))

Comment: When I access the above page with JavaScript disabled, it returns a pardon page which questions if you are a bot. The 200 is correct because it successfully served a page but it isn't what you are looking for. Print your soup to verify. Looks like you will need to use a different library to access this site/page.

Comment: Thank you for your message, here is where Im stuck as Im new at this, I thought when I get 200 then I can scrape but apparently not, which Library will give me access do you think? so I can investigate - Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use these headers instead, (the website use cookies to communicate with incoming requests):

```
headers = {
    "authority": "www.controlleremea.co.uk",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "referer": "https://www.controlleremea.co.uk/listings/search?Category=3&page=1",
    "accept-language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,ar;q=0.5",
    "cookie": "reese84=3:J/F1EuQpZop+MobxryNEOg==:kUVoa/qtRRr5AN0gVYTZXcwmj1FVj4gG1wfhRdsLR7LnmFIJDdi0zWMHh1qfSjZtJTFBApOE0CwFi2+h8XxHjh5Iv3cTr1G5QtMfs2FW+N2RlTujZiRRV4bqs0hB8QCWUxpm6fwsI42YnFvrVnMkGGqXbhUdIRaYuGSV7ygJ/AqSiGEqwiCmu7FjREQP2hFq7N6exezLOzaaMcXtKavR1SVqgyW5xtN32+PmygrTd6wrmWbTeYUf+6iTkOmkcBOdjeWK7NBmVIbJo4qw9qxJwvw3VBihbG+rGFoqQw4YbUMoaNa+mtOL3bg/a4+BTiH+3C32xrubYNN4/I4LgY0ornQeohb1GmOCYlYrdTvHgcX/b0d12nPGURMd+SYob+2AfyKkQ5xtMwkiQKwakMua/FO3Ng0ue2OHhuGEFKuVuEE=:IbJEnJ7J7IVUXMBj4/rHqgdgbolriJdbgxJbvW71zHg=; UserID=ID=E4U814OFfiu3luD6Jx7tWcjNlzHWjxKzTAZ3TXd98f2JBZ2p4O6k4LrTl9Ls3%2fFXDXjgFCRA4zotP0is2FEY5Q%3d%3d&LV=NVDRfm9pDDc4R7axU2PhLcsGPHdA5j5TJ9hJxVUwt107bwiDgdR%2b1SBmOxy12WajDx0B2LHJQa3ES1przM5isHNW4yOv341I; Tracking=SessionStarted=1&UserReferrer=https%3a%2f%2fwww.controlleremea.co.uk%2flistings%2fsearch%3fCategory%3d3%26page%3d1&GUID=57129217415440876607; __RequestVerificationToken=ZmF0RAJQhnZOvFXUi4RUSW_ivF5nAG89f5C8ZfYHfwpu5TZWl6ihLXxRGRbEu6WUoti-6g2; BIGipServerwww.controller.tradesites_http_pool=914467008.20480.0000; _ga_YW84BNZ375=GS1.1.1642080823.1.0.1642080823.0; _uetsid=6db08c60747511ec8c49372682f2631d; _uetvid=6db0a3d0747511ecbe496f12a35f4661; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; _ga=GA1.3.1809682930.1642080824; _gid=GA1.3.1817987658.1642080825; ASP.NET_SessionId=frymnmuedyx2icwdqxi2dygi; UserSettingsCookie=screenSize=1600|789"
}
```

Comment: Thank you much appreciated